# Command lines : use returning value as argument for another command

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I've got two commands, the first one is `rhythmbox-client --print-playing`, which prints (returns) a string into the terminal, and another one, `notify-send text`, which sends a system notification. Now I'm trying to write something like `notify-send | rhythmbox-client --print-playing` or `notify-send ${rhythmbox-client --print-playing}`, but I must admit that I'm not really comfortable with bash scripting...

How do I write this ?

Comment: Your second try was close, use `$()` instead of `${}`.

Comment: Oups ! It prints then `Invalid number of options.`

Comment: Don't forget to quote: `notify-send "$(...)"`